# PHP Amazon S3 Uploads And Tags

Tags: php, amazon-s3, tags

I'm coding a video sharing site. I'm using S3 to store and serve up the videos. I've coded tags for the videos in my MySQL database but I saw that S3 supports settings tags on uploaded files. Here's the code I'm using to upload files:

```
try {
                //Create a S3Client
                $s3Client = new S3Client([
                    'region' => 'us-east-1',
                    'version' => 'latest',
                    'credentials' => [
                        'key' => '',
                        'secret' => ''
                    ]
                ]);
                $result = $s3Client->putObject([
                    'Bucket' => $bucket,
                    'Key' => $assetFilename,
                    'SourceFile' => $fileTmpPath,
                    'Metadata'   => array(
                        'title' => $requestAr['title'],
                        'description' => $requestAr['description']
                    )
                ]);
                $s3Client->waitUntil('ObjectExists', array(
                    'Bucket' => $bucket,
                    'Key'    => $assetFilename
                ));
            } catch (S3Exception $e) {
                returnError($e->getMessage());
            }
```

This is a 2 part question. First, how can I specify tags here? I can't find any PHP examples. Next, let's say someone uploads a video and they put a tag on it. S3 tags are key/value pairs. What should I set for the keys? I was thinking of just using something like [tag1, tag2, tag3] for each video and the value of those being the tag strings. Here's the S3 tags doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an object tag, simply pass the `Tagging` element to the `putObject()` parameters. In your case, it'd be like this:

```
$result = $s3Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $assetFilename,
    'SourceFile' => $fileTmpPath,
    'Tagging' => 'category=tag1', // your tag here!
    'Metadata'   => array(
        'title' => $requestAr['title'],
        'description' => $requestAr['description']
    )
]);
```

Notice the tag is a simple `key=value` string. As a "thinking ahead" measure, I'd make the tags be `category=tagValue`, so you can categorize them and eventually add more tag categories. If you do `tag1=true`, then it'll get messy quick.

- [putObject() reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject)

Comment: Thanks. As for categories though, I hadn't even planned to have tag categories. Does a site like YouTube even use them? I think they just have you input a list of tags and not categorize them. I don't know how I'd categorize them unless I asked the users to do it when tagging (Not something they will likely want to deal with).

Comment: What I mean is, maybe now you want to have tags, `movie`, `music video`, etc. But later you might want to have `>1 min`, `>1 hour` or whatever, and if you have them like `movie=true`, or `>1min=true`, rather than `cateogory=movie`, `length=>1min`, then you'll have all the tags in the same "namespace" and it'll be a mess.

Comment: Okay. Now that I see tagging info exists there, shouldn't it be done more like this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobjecttagging

Comment: That might be a bit cleaner but you need to think of the responsiveness of your page. Doing it that way you need to make 2 roundtrips to the endpoint instead of one, which might be slower. And they need to be in series, not parallel, because you need to wait for the object to be done uplaoding to tag it. To **get** the tags though, you definitely need to make a `getObjectTagging()` call, no way around that.

Comment: So for multiple tags in your example, how should I separate them?

Comment: It's just a query string. You can do this: `red=true&blue=false`