# How to add tags when uploading an object to an S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I've been working with some example code from Amazon to get a script to upload an object to a bucket in version 3 of the php sdk for aws. I can get the object to upload to a bucket, but I'm trying to add a tag to this new object during this PutObject method call. I've worked through a few examples that I found, but nothing has worked for me. Here is my php code so far:

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => $config['s3BucketName'],
    'Key' => 'file_upload_direct.mp4',
    'Tagging' => 'status=notProcessed',
]);
```

The Tagging property doesn't get applied and doesn't give any error when the form is sent. I've seen a few ways of adding tags to uploads, but none of those have worked for me. I'm trying to avoid using the PutObjectTagging method since that seems to be extra work if I'm able to define the tag in the PutObject method. I'm not sure if the issue is trying to use the PutObject method in the getCommand or not, but as far as I can tell you should be able to pass the normal parameters as an array like this. Has anyone been able to get this to work, or is there a different way I should be trying to accomplish this?

Comment: Might be relevant: [PHP Amazon S3 Uploads And Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46249148/174777) and [AWS s3 putObject Tagging is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60437131/174777)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JohnRotenstein. I came across those when I as first searching online for a solution. Unfortunately, those haven't worked for me. I did noticed that I gave the wrong permission to my bucket for looking at the putObject tagging. I used s3:putBucketTagging instead of s3:putObjectTagging. Once I made the change, it still didn't work. Since I'm still developing and testing, I gave all the permissions to the bucket policy, but I still can't tag the object on upload, unfortunately.

Comment: You could _temporarily_ give your code `s3:*` permission to determine whether the problem is related to permissions. These permissions should be given to your app, not the bucket.

Comment: I have a similar problem with direct upload. Everything works, but nothing arrives in the tags field. I had to give the bucket a policy to paste tags. Still no tags, but no errors either...

Answer (score 0):

it is better later than never, right?

The problem here is that AWS Docs are poor on emphasising important details like:

> Note: Not all operation parameters are supported when using pre-signed URLs. Certain parameters, such as SSECustomerKey, ACL, Expires, ContentLength, or Tagging must be provided as headers when sending a request.

You can find these in API Docs and easy to overlook.

This means you prepare data to create a signature with this:

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
  'Bucket' => $config['s3BucketName'],
  'Key' => 'file_upload_direct.mp4',
  'Tagging' => 'status=notProcessed',
]);
```

Then when you get the URL back from

```
$s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+5 minutes');
```

And you PUT to that URL, you have to also send HTTP Header `X-Amz-Tagging: status=notProcessed`

Another important thing to keep in mind is that, if you are PUTting from the frontend, your bucket must have CORS policies properly set up and allow headers like `x-amz-tagging`.